# documentclass{book}: Page content aligned on bottom of page

Tags: document-classes, minipage

I'm still a beginner on LaTeX, but at the moment I'm working on a book. I'm working with Gummi and for some reason I started my work with `\documentclass{article}`. As I changed the `\documentclass` to `{book}`, the content of the page was aligned to the bottom of the page - when I change back to `{article}` everything is normal again. 
I already searched on the net, but I could neither find a reason for that behaviour nor a solution to my problem...

Anyone an idea how to solve this? I give a piece of my code of a page with that problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\geometry{a4paper, top=20mm, left=30mm, right=10mm, bottom=20mm,
headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{Huge}
\textbf{1934 - 1949}
\end{Huge}
\linebreak \linebreak

\centering
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{Bilder/robert2.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{9cm}
\parbox{9cm}{
\textbf{1934:}\\
Die Nationalsozialisten festigen ihre Macht...  \\
\textbf{1939:}\\
Die Wehrmacht greift Polen an und beginnt somit den 2. Weltkrieg.\\
\textbf{1945:}\\
Am 8. Mai Am 8. Mai kapituliert die Wehrmacht bedingungslos...\\
\textbf{1948:}\\
Die Westzonen führen die D-Mark ein, woraufhin Moskau...\\
\textbf{1949:}\\
Aus den westlichen Besatzungszonen gründet sich die... 
}
\end{minipage}
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ p{3.2cm} p{13cm} }
Juli 1934 & some text\\
Dezember 1943 & another text in column \\
September 1949 & more and more text in right column \\
\end{tabular}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: As to why, it seems to be related to the `\pagebreak` which could be defined differently in this class, but you can manually overcome it by placing a `\vfill` prior to the `\pagebreak`, OR eliminating the `\pagebreak` altogether, OR by replacing the `\pagebreak` with a `\clearpage`.

Comment: That was fast, and worked! Thank you, good to know about the \vfill option!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book class defaults to `\flushbottom` but you can issue `\raggedbottom` if you do not want latex to align the bottom line of each page.

Don't do this though!

```
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
```

You should almost never use `\\`  or `\linebreak` outside of the use for `\\`  to end tabular rows. Certainly never use them with no intervening text, or at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: thanks fot the supplement. So you tell me not to use \linebreaks, but don't mention why. It works for me (beginner) - so what's the disadvantage?